# MongoDB split string and Update

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have document structure like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3a77d9d274eb44bc85d7c8"),
    "b_id" : 3,
    "b_display_tag" : "Veg Curry, Non Veg Curry"
}
```

I am able to get the first element from the string in `b_display_tag` using split and aggregate query:

```
db.blogs.aggregate([
    {$project: {"b_display_tag": {$arrayElemAt:[{$split: ["$b_display_tag" , ","]}, 0]}}}
])
```

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3a77d9d274eb44bc85d7c8"),
    "b_display_tag" : "Veg Curry"
}
```

How can I update `b_display_tag` in the whole document with the first element from comma separated string?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit about this `How can I update b_display_tag in the whole document with above query?`. I would like to know you just want to update `b_display_tag` field or the complete document.

Comment: Yes. Update only `b_display_tag`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below query to update b_display_tag. It will split b_tags using separator(') and update b_display_tag  with first index.

```
db.blogs.find().forEach(function (blog) 
{
    if (blog.b_tags)
    {
        blog.b_display_tag=blog.b_tags.split(',');
        blog.b_display_tag=blog.b_display_tag[0];

        db.blogs.save(blog);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) in the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) to write it into a new collection, since here we need to update the existing collection `blogs` use the same collection name in [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/).

```
db.blogs.aggregate([
   {$project: 
      {
         _id:1,
         b_id:1,
         b_display_tag:{$arrayElemAt:[{$split:["$b_display_tag", ","]}, 0]}
      }
   },
   {$out:"blogs"}
 ]);
```